# How to set specific language for all pages in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I've translated 2 language in '**app/Language**' folder and set language switcher. Currently translation works fine for base url like `example.com/en` and `example.com/sp`.

My problem is when visitor visits other page like `/post/cats/123` then How I set the language for all view page. What is the standard way for language setting in codeigniter 4.

Language folder -

[image]

language switcher code.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url('en') ?>">English</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url('sp') ?>">Spanish</a>
</div>
```

Route-

```
$routes->get('/{locale}', 'Language::index');
```

Language class -

```
class Language extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
         $locale = $this->request->getLocale();
         $this->request->setLocale($locale);
         return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I got a solution for multi language in codeigniter-4  myself that I described now. My **view code** is here that is clickable for selection a language -

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url('lang/en'); ?>">English</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url('lang/es'); ?>">Español</a>
```

then I used a **route** for language-

```
$routes->get('/lang/{locale}', 'Language::index');
```

For this **route** I created a class **Language** with a method **index**-

```
class Language extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {   $session = session();
        $locale = $this->request->getLocale();
        $session->remove('lang');
        $session->set('lang',$locale);
        $url = base_url();
        return redirect()->to($url);     
    }
}
```

Here I enabled session to store selected language and removed old language from session. `$locale = $this->request->getLocale();` With this request I received selected language and stored into into session `$session->set('lang',$locale);` and redirect it to base url.

In codeigniter-4 default **BaseController** in **initController** method, I set language `$language->setLocale($session->lang);` for all controllers that I extends for other.

```
class BaseController extends Controller{
    public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
      $session = \Config\Services::session();
      $language = \Config\Services::language();
      $language->setLocale($session->lang);
    }
}
```

Here I enabled **language Library** as a service `$language = \Config\Services::language();` and set language with this method `$language->setLocale($session->lang);` using session data.

Comment: works really well. might I just add that in case you want to validate the lanf for some reason, CI4 reads 2 char codes, eg. 'en'